# How to check why @BeanInject in Camel does not initialize member?

Tags: nullpointerexception, apache-camel, javabeans

I have the following context configuration:

```
<bean id="propertiesFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:conf.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="properties" ref="propertiesFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageThrottlerHolder" class="foo.bar.common.MessageThrottlerHolder"/>
<bean id="cassandraRoute" class="foo.bar.routes.CassandraRouteBuilder"/>
```

Then in both classes: `MessageThrottlerHolder` and in `CassandraRouteBuilder` there is:

```
@BeanInject
Properties properties;
```

Wonderful.

But `CassandraRouteBuilder` may/could use `properties` without NPE, as `properties` are well initialized. 
On the other hand the `MessageThrottlerHolder` is not able to use `properties` as in the constructor `properties` are ***null*** and there is no way to initialize them.

How can I check why `properties` are null?
What can be wrong, that `@BeanInject` somehow does not initialize `properties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this wrong if you think that `Properties` are somehow Camel property placeholder or anything like that.

Camel's `@BeanInject` is for looking up bean in the Camel register via a bean name/id, as a poor-mans Spring IoC. If you are using Spring then you can use the Spring `@Autowired` or whatever they have for that.

If you want to access properties from the properties placeholder, then you can inject `CamelContext` and use its API for resolving: http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.20.0/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#resolvePropertyPlaceholders-java.lang.String-

Or use Camel's `@PropertyInject` instead where you specify the key name to lookup. I am not sure if Spring has any similar annotation for looking up properties, as you have turned on the camel-spring bridge. You can also try to look into that.

Comment: I know that I am doing something wrong :-). But how to check what is wrong? 

Now I have: `@Inject
    private CamelContext context;
    @PropertyInject( "processing.throughput" )
    private String kafkaThroughput;
    @BeanInject( "properties" )
    private Properties properties;` in my bean and still in debugger I see all those fields are set to ***null*** in the moment, when I am reaching the constructor. So there is somewhere very basic problem.

Comment: Those fields are injected post constructor

Comment: In meanwhile I found it as well myself :-). 
I switched all possible logs to TRACE level. Then I had seen that parameters injection happens after constructor was called. 
To solve the problem I had made constructor empty and moved any functionality which is initiating instance using given parameters to *init* method. In Camel context I had splited object instantiation in two parts: 1. parametrization and 2. initialization done by *init*.
Thanks for inspiration.